# Docker.DotNet Package How to Prune Containers with filters

Tags: .net, docker, containers

I was trying to prune containers by applying filter using Docker.Dotnet.

I found a function to achieve this

*public async Task PruneContainersAsync(ContainersPruneParameters parameters, CancellationToken cancellationToken)*

But I am unable to correlate between the expected format in which arguments have to be passed to achieve a prune of containers which are exited say 60 min back.

```
namespace Docker.DotNet.Models
{
    [DataContract]
    public class ContainersPruneParameters // (main.ContainersPruneParameters)
    {
        [QueryStringParameter("filters", false, typeof(MapQueryStringConverter))]
        public IDictionary<string, IDictionary<string, bool>> Filters { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Can someone help me with expected arguments to be passed to such function. Per docker api spec the arguments for filter are strings.

Note: I am a relatively new C# developer.